# Program that is supposed to determine whether or not the user typed an even or odd integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

A program that determines whether the integer the user entered is even or odd. I keep getting errors for the elif statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
while True:
    reply=input('enter an even or odd integer:') #ASK USER TO ENTER AN EVEN OR ODD INTEGER
    if reply=='stop':break #PRINTS OUT THE WORD 'STOP' IF THE USER WANTS TO EXIT THE PROGRAM
    try:
        num=int(reply) #USER ENTERS NUMBER
    except:
        print('you did not an integer integer')# IF THE USER PRINTS ANYTHING OTHER THAN AN INTEGER
    else:
        if num%2==0:
            print('you printed an even integer')#iF USER TYPES AN EVEN INTEGER, THEY PRINT OUT THIS STATEMENT

    elif num%2!=0:    #IF THE TYPES AN ODD INTEGER , PROGRAM IS THEN SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY THE STATEMENT BELOW
       print('you printed an odd integer')
```

Comment: Need correct indentation.

Comment: Please include the exact error you’re receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `elif` to an if statement, there is no corresponding `if` block for it in your current code.

```
while True:
    reply=input('enter an even or odd integer:') #ASK USER TO ENTER AN EVEN OR ODD INTEGER
    if reply=='stop':break #PRINTS OUT THE WORD 'STOP' IF THE USER WANTS TO EXIT THE PROGRAM
    try:
        num=int(reply) #USER ENTERS NUMBER
    except:
        print('you did not an integer integer')# IF THE USER PRINTS ANYTHING OTHER THAN AN INTEGER
    else:
        if num%2==0:
            print('you printed an even integer')#iF USER TYPES AN EVEN INTEGER, THEY PRINT OUT THIS STATEMENT

    if num%2!=0:    #IF THE TYPES AN ODD INTEGER , PROGRAM IS THEN SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY THE STATEMENT BELOW
       print('you printed an odd integer')
```

or, convert it to an else statement and indent it with your if statement in else block of try-except:

```
while True:
    reply=input('enter an even or odd integer:') #ASK USER TO ENTER AN EVEN OR ODD INTEGER
    if reply=='stop':break #PRINTS OUT THE WORD 'STOP' IF THE USER WANTS TO EXIT THE PROGRAM
    try:
        num=int(reply) #USER ENTERS NUMBER
    except:
        print('you did not an integer integer')# IF THE USER PRINTS ANYTHING OTHER THAN AN INTEGER
    else:
        if num%2==0:
            print('you printed an even integer')#iF USER TYPES AN EVEN INTEGER, THEY PRINT OUT THIS STATEMENT
        else:    #IF THE TYPES AN ODD INTEGER , PROGRAM IS THEN SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY THE STATEMENT BELOW
           print('you printed an odd integer')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `if` and `elif` are mismatched.. You need to indent more

```
while True:
    reply=input('enter an even or odd integer:') #ASK USER TO ENTER AN EVEN OR ODD INTEGER
    if reply=='stop':break #PRINTS OUT THE WORD 'STOP' IF THE USER WANTS TO EXIT THE PROGRAM
    try:
        num=int(reply) #USER ENTERS NUMBER
    except:
        print('you did not an integer integer')# IF THE USER PRINTS ANYTHING OTHER THAN AN INTEGER
    else:
          if num%2==0:
            print('you printed an even integer')#iF USER TYPES AN EVEN INTEGER, THEY PRINT OUT THIS STATEMENT

          elif num%2!=0:    #IF THE TYPES AN ODD INTEGER , PROGRAM IS THEN SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY THE STATEMENT BELOW
            print('you printed an odd integer')
```

Must be of same Indent level

Answer (score 0):

Order and indent matters, the correct order is `if-elif-else`. You can't use it like `if-else-elif`. If your `elif` statement under the `else`, then you have to put them at the same line.

```
else:
    if num%2==0:
        print('you printed an even integer')#iF USER TYPES AN EVEN INTEGER, THEY PRINT OUT THIS STATEMENT

    elif num%2!=0:    #IF THE TYPES AN ODD INTEGER , PROGRAM IS THEN SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY THE STATEMENT BELOW
   print('you printed an odd integer')
```

Answer (score 0):

A much nicer way to write your program would be:

```
while True:
reply=input('enter an even or odd integer:') #ASK USER TO ENTER AN EVEN OR ODD INTEGER
if reply=='stop':
    break #TYPE OUT THE WORD 'STOP' IF THE USER WANTS TO EXIT THE PROGRAM
else:
    try:
        num=int(reply) #USER ENTERS NUMBER
        if num%2==0:
            print('you printed an even integer')#iF USER TYPES AN EVEN INTEGER, THEY PRINT OUT THIS STATEMENT

        elif num%2!=0:    #IF THE TYPES AN ODD INTEGER , PROGRAM IS THEN SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY THE STATEMENT BELOW
            print('you printed an odd integer')

    except:
            print('you did not an integer integer')# IF THE USER PRINTS ANYTHING OTHER THAN AN INTEGER
```

Previously your conditional statements were mismatched, thus giving you an error.

Answer (score -1):

You have an indentation bug. The last elif should be at the same `if num%2==0` indentation level.